# Pandas: rearrange multindex DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, series

I have a Multiindex column DataFrame with the following configuration:

```
                Cat_1                      Cat_2
            sub-cat_1  sub-cat_2    sub-cat_1  sub-cat_2 
metric_one     10         20            1          2
metric_two     15         10            3          4
```

I want to achieve the following result:

```
                      Cat_1    Cat_2         
metric_one sub-cat_1    10      1
           sub-cat_2    20      2
metric_two sub-cat_1    15      3
           sub-cat_2    10      4
```

I tried some strategies (unstack, stack,swaplevel) but I can't figure out how can I achieve that. Any recommendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) working nice, but necessary `MultiIndex` in columns:

```
print (df.columns)
MultiIndex(levels=[['Cat_1', 'Cat_2'], ['sub-cat_1', 'sub-cat_2']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]])

df1 = df.stack()
print (df1)
                      Cat_1  Cat_2
metric_one sub-cat_1     10      1
           sub-cat_2     20      2
metric_two sub-cat_1     15      3
           sub-cat_2     10      4
```

Comment: Jez, 
You are totally correct.

I had changed one cell up in my 'jupyter notebook', so this was affecting my results. 

Thank you for the answer. I will accept that!! =)